# Tibco Bw http process to fetch webpage from public website is unable to decode in browser

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I am new to tibco bw . I am implementing a process that will take a HTTP request from browser, and send an http request to en.wikinews.org and display the webpage on the browser .

I have designed the process, but the browser is not able to display the webpage.

This is my process flow -> Http receiver -->Send HTTP request (to en.wikinews.org/wiki/Main_Page) -->Send HTTP response. But when I test it using browser, I am getting unreadable characters.

Any pointers will be very helpful

PS- this exercise is a part of bw examples (coming with installation, but the example is implemented in older bw version)

Comment: What HTTP headers are you getting back and are you sending them all through to the browser?

Comment: I mapped all the header fields  in the send http response(except content-encoding field )  but in browser i can see only binary data , but when i map content-encoding (from Send HTTP request output) , the browser is not able to decode at all.I saw the server is sending data in gzip format but some how its not passing through correctly to browser thru Tibco .

Comment: Can you check the "Input" of your "Send HTTP response"?

Comment: you have map the content encoding field as it tells the browser how either decompress or decode the response ..